# How to join two matrices in fprintf in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two matrices A and B as given below:

```
A = [1
     2
     3
     4
     5]

B = [10  11  12  13
     15  16  17  18
     17  12  15  13
     20  21  22  17
     40  41  32  33]
```

and I would like to output it to a text file in the form given below:

**Desired text output**

```
1  10  11  12  13
2  15  16  17  18
3  17  12  15  13
4  20  21  22  17
5  40  41  32  33
```

I tried it with this code but it does not work:

```
clc
clear all
A = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5];
B = [10, 11, 12, 13;
     15, 16, 17, 18;
     17, 12, 15, 13;
     20, 21, 22, 17;
     40, 41, 32, 33;]
fid = fopen('output.dat', 'w');
fprintf(fid, '%f\t', A, [repmat('%f\t', 1, size(B, 2)) '\n'], B');
```

How to join and output the matrices with fprintf in MATLAB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Anatch is right, you can use `horzcat(A,B)` to horizontally concatenate two matrices. Though a simpler way to do the same thing is simply saying `[A B]`, to concatenate horizontally or `[C; A]` to concatenate vertically.

As for printing these results, @SamuelNLP 's solution works, but here's an alternative, which is faster for large matrices:

```
A = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5];
B = [10, 11, 12, 13;
     15, 16, 17, 18;
     17, 12, 15, 13;
     20, 21, 22, 17;
     40, 41, 32, 33;];

ALL = [A B];

ALL_cell = mat2cell(ALL, ones(size(ALL,1),1), size(ALL,2));

fID = fopen('output.dat','w');
f = @(x) fprintf(fID,'%s\n',sprintf('%f\t',x));
cellfun(f,ALL_cell);
fclose(fID);
```

In `output.dat` :

```
1.000000    10.000000   11.000000   12.000000   13.000000   
2.000000    15.000000   16.000000   17.000000   18.000000   
3.000000    17.000000   12.000000   15.000000   13.000000   
4.000000    20.000000   21.000000   22.000000   17.000000   
5.000000    40.000000   41.000000   32.000000   33.000000
```

Comment: @Anatch: Why is this not what he wants?

Comment: Because he does'nt want a matrix full of zeros otherwise he could have used the zeros() function !!!!
He wants the desired text output he wrote in is question, do you need glasses ?

Comment: @Anatch The output that I show is _exactly_ what he (or she) wanted. In the question he uses `fprintf('%f' ...)`, which prints _floats_ (or singles as they're called in matlab), so the result is in the form of X.YYYY, where X is an integer and the Ys are decimals, i.e. the number `one` is printed as `1.000`. I guess those are the zeros that you were referring to - otherwise I have no idea what you're talking about. Also, a side note: I do have glasses. ;)

Comment: Oh so sorry, my bad !

Answer (score 1):

@Anatch answer is right,

here's an example code,

```
clc
clear

A = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5];
B = [10, 11, 12, 13;
    15, 16, 17, 18;
    17, 12, 15, 13;
    20, 21, 22, 17;
    40, 41, 32, 33;];

C = horzcat(A, B);

fid = fopen('output.dat', 'w');
for ii = 1:size(C, 1)
    for jj = 1:size(C, 2)
        fprintf(fid, '%d\t', C(ii,jj));
    end
    fprintf(fid, '\n');
end
```

**Output.dat**

```
1   10  11  12  13  
2   15  16  17  18  
3   17  12  15  13  
4   20  21  22  17  
5   40  41  32  33
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the horzcat(A,B) method that you have to use:

horzcat will concatenate the two matrices horizontally